# GLMERTREE ranefstart and offset

Tags: tree, offset, mixed-models, party

I am using `lmertree` to fit a degradation model of the form

`ln(y)=offset(ln(t0_value))+b*time`

where `y` is the outcome of interest,  `t0_value` is the initial concentration of the substance at time 0, `b` is the parameter to be estimated and `time` is a variable measuring time. This is a longitudinal study, therefore there exist an id variable which indexes measures form the same subject (`HC`), and finally some covariates a the level of the subject (i.e non time dependent) which are of interest.

I have being experimenting different kinds of `lmertree` models and exploring different options in the function, and I got confused with the options `ranefstart` and `offset`, in particular, if I set  `ranefstart=T` I get stunningly different results from that when `ranefstart=NULL`

Now I show some of the code used to fit the models:

```
lmm_tree1 <- lmertree(log(y) ~-1+ time | ((-1+time)|HC) |
                       TD+EP2+DFA+DTCX+TIF+SCV, 
                       data = z0l,
                       offset = log(z0l[,"value_t0"]),
                       ranefstart =T)
```

```
lmm_tree2 <- lmertree(log(y) ~-1+ time | ((-1+time)|HC) |
                       TD+EP2+DFA+DTCX+TIF+SCV, 
                       data = z0l,
                       offset = log(z0l[,"value_t0"]),
                       ranefstart =NULL)
```

```
lmm_tree <- lmertree(log(y) ~-1+ time | ((-1+time)|HC) |
                       TD+EP2+DFA+DTCX+TIF+SCV, 
                       data = z0l,
                       offset = log(z0l[,"value_t0"]),
                       ranefstart = z0l[,"value_t0"])
```

Note that I have eliminated the intercept and used the offset option to specify the model that I want.

Models `lmm_tree2` and `lmm_tree3` are very similar (they differ in depth but splits criteria are quite similar), however, model `lmm_tree1` has only one node.

The question is: when and why should I use the ranefstart option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Argument `ranefstart`**

Function `lmertree` iterates between estimating the LM tree-part of the model (here `log(y) ~ -1 + time | TD + EP2 + DFA + DTCX + TIF + SCV`) and the random-effects part of the model (here `log(y) ~ ((-1+time)|HC)`).  Argument `ranefstart` controls the initialization, but this will often be inconsequential. It might be consequential when there is variation in the response (here `log(y)`) that can potentially be explained by both the LM tree as well as the random effects:

- By default, estimation is initialized with the LM tree part; then this variation will likely be captured by the tree.
- If you override the default and specify `ranefstart = TRUE`, `lmertree` will initialize estimation with the random-effects part; then this variation will likely be captured by the random effects.

You obtained quite similar results using `ranefstart = NULL` and `ranefstart = TRUE`, indicating that the final model is not sensitive to initialization with the tree versus the random effects. In that case, using the default is fine.

By specifying `ranefstart = z0l[,"value_t0"]`, variable `z0l[,"value_t0"]` will be included as an offset in the linear predictor in the first iteration of the estimation. In further iterations, this offset will no longer be used. Because you already specified `offset = log(z0l[,"value_t0"])`, in the first iteration the offset is doubled; this could send the iterative estimation into a wrong direction, and further iterations might not be able to correct for this anymore. This could explain why you got such different results.

The use of the `ranefstart` argument is useful only, when you expect that a substantial part of the variance in the response can be potentially accounted for by the tree, as well as by the random effects, and you prefer this variation to be accounted for by the random-effects part of the model, not by the tree.

**Argument `cluster`**

In addition: You mention you have subject-level (level-II) partitioning covariates. I would advise the use of the `cluster` argument in that case, because by default the parameter-stability tests employed for selecting the splitting variables assume the partitioning variables to be measured at the lowest level (level I). By specifying `cluster = HC`, the parameter-stability tests will account for the partitioning variables being measured at level II. When the parameter-stability tests are performed at level I, the tests may be overpowered.

**Plotting level-II group size in terminal nodes**

In a future version of **`glmertree`** it would be nice to have an argument of the plotting function to specify whether *n* should reflect sample size at level I, II, etc. For now, I can suggest the following approach:

```
## Fit an example lmertree with partitioning variables at level II
library("glmertree")
data("GrowthCurveDemo", package = "glmertree")
form <- y ~ time | person | x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8
lt <- lmertree(form, cluster = person, data = GrowthCurveDemo)

## Create a tree copy with node sample sizes at level II
node_ids <- predict(lt, type = "node")
lt_node <- as.list(lt$tree$node)
for (i in unique(node_ids)) {
  lt_node[[i]]$info$nobs <-
    length(unique(lt$tree$data[node_ids == i, "(cluster)"]))
}
lt2 <- lt
lt2$tree$node <- as.partynode(lt_node)

## Compare resulting trees:
plot(lt, which = "tree", fitted = "marginal",
     main = "n is group size at level I")
plot(lt2, which = "tree", fitted = "marginal", 
     main = "n is group size at level II")
```

Note that what you would need to adjust for your own code/tree is that your `(g)lmertree` should be named `lt`. Also, the use of `fitted = "marginal"` is not required, but for longitudinal data often makes for a more intuitive plot. See `?plot.lmertree` for more info.

Comment: Marjolein I have been wandering if it is possible to generate the tree plot providing counts not for observation at level I but at level II. In my case the clusters are patients and would be nice to know how many patients are there in each terminal node. Off course I know this info can be extracted from the data slot of the lmertree object. Ty for the answer.

Comment: @NicolasMolano Excellent idea! I have also wondered about this; only after your question it occurred to me how to attempt this. Added an example above, hope this helps!